# How do I drop a bash shell from within Python?

Tags: python

i'm working on a python tcp shell; I'd like to be able to telnet to a port, and have it prompt me with a shell: ex.

```
$ telnet localhost 5555
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
$
```

The answer below was quite helpful in getting me on my way. Here's the working code.

```
import SocketServer, os, subprocess
class EchoRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler ):
    def setup(self):
        print self.client_address, 'connected!'
        self.request.send(str(self.client_address) + '\n')
        self.request.send(os.system('sh'))
    def handle(self):
        data = 'dummy'
        while data:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            self.request.send(os.popen(data.strip()).read())
            if data.strip() == 'bye':
                return

    def finish(self):
        print self.client_address, 'disconnected!'
        self.request.send('bye ' + str(self.client_address) + '\n')

server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('', 7784), EchoRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: 1. What happens if you run "/bin/tcsh" from your shell command line?
2. tcsh != bash . bash might be in /bin/bash. run 'which bash'

Comment: @Paul: It's not because of the "wrong" shell being executed. It's because `popen` isn't the right tool for doing anything interactive, such as an interactive shell.

Comment: Could you be getting a python command line >>> and a shell prompt at the same time?

Comment: @Chris - I'd tend to agree.  Does 'drop a bash shell' mean to provide an interactive shell to the program's human user?  I guess it could.  It is difficult to know from the question what they wanted it to do or why they want to invoke a shell.

Answer (score 9):

```
import os
os.system('sh')  # or bash, tcsh, zsh, whatever. :-P
```